# Twilio conversations

Tags: twilio, twilio-conversations

When using twilio Conversations API the billing is associated with active users and media storage.

When using a client SDK you create access tokens with a user identity.
When using the Twilio Conversations API, you use your account SID and an auth token.

I am not intending to use the client SDK so when using the API I can add participants and then send messages to a conversation.

When I create a participant I must create an identity as a parameter.

Is this the correct way to creating this participant via this API, is this how I am charged? What is stopping me from always using the same identity and therefore only ever having one active user?

The reason why I am using the Twilio Conversations API is that I am attempting to abstract my UI away from Twilio by not using the SDK. Instead, the user will authenticate with my application. When using my API, the subject from my applications JWT will be used as the identity.